# Responsive 2-column layout trouble

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, frontend

I'm having trouble solving this puzzle: I'm using a 2-column layout with a fixed-width right column and a left column which takes out the remaining space. Both heights are variable. So something like this:

```
<div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
<div class="main-area">main content</div>

<style>
.sidebar { float: right; width: 250px; }
.main-area { position: relative; overflow: hidden; }
</style>
```

Ok, so up to here everything is fine. But here comes the tricky bit. I'm using CSS3 to enable a css change when reaching a max-width of 750px. I want the sidebar to break down below and have a 100% width (so it becomes a footer for the main content). But, because in the HTML code the sidebar div is required to be first it always appears above the main area.

Any ideas on how to lay this out?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `sidebar` to the right, i.e coming after `main-area` is not an option in html code?

Comment: Why is it required that the sidebar appear before your main content in the HTML hierarchy?

There is no limitation here unless you have created a limitation of your own.

Comment: Actually `sidebar` can move to under `main-area` automatically if you put your `<div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>` after `<div class="main-area">main content</div>`

Comment: In a 2-column structure, with a float-right sidebar and a main area that occupies all the remaining space, the float-right is required to come first in the html markup. If I put the sidebar after main-area this wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: @James This will work fine whether the sidebar is before or after the content.  Since you are floating the element, you are essentially pulling the element out of the DOM.  So essentially, when it is floated it doesn't matter if it comes before or after.  It does matter though when you switch to float: none; for your breakpoint, so just move it after the content.

Comment: Hey Michael. Of course I've tried to put main-area before sidebar. But when you do this, main-area doesn't take up the remaining space (window width - 250px of sidebar). This only works when sidebar comes first in the markup. When you put main-area first, this occupies 100% width since the width is not defined.

Comment: @James , can you take your code and place it in a JSFiddle so I can take look?  jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is **no**.  You can't make your sidebar move beneath the content in your breakpoint if the sidebar falls before the content area in your HTML.  At least... Not without javascript and a bunch of craziness.

That said...  Just move your sidebar **below** your main-content div.  Semantically there is no reason for you not to.

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="main-area">main content</div>
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
</section>
```

Some CSS changes are required to achieve this however.  It's not quite as simply done as you had it previously, but not especially difficult either.

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 250px;
}
.main-area {
    background: red;
    margin-right: 250px;
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating it working.](http://jsfiddle.net/8YLXy/)

Feel free to add varying amounts of content to either the main-content area or the sidebar and you'll see that both still have varying heights that don't interfere with each other.

Comment: I need main-area to occupy remaining space left by the sidebar (container width - sidebar width), not 100% of container. That's why your suggestion doesn't work for me Thanks for the 767px suggestion, I was just using 750 as an example.

Comment: @James - I have realized I was wrong with my original suggestion after some testing.  I have edited my answer with a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="main-area">main content</div>
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.container { 
     position: relative; 
     max-width: 1024px; /* could be width: x% as well*/ 
}

.sidebar { 
     position: absolute; 
     right: 0; top: 0; 
     width: 250px;
}

.main-area { 
     margin-right: 260px; /* sidebar width plus 10px gap */ 
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {

     .sidebar {
          position: static;
          width: 100%;
     }

     .main-area {
         width: 100%;
         margin-right: 0;
     }

}
```

Comment: with absolute position is complicated because you don't know the heights.

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick reply.
I probably should of made clear that the sidebar is on the RIGHT. That's why there is a float: right. I'm not sure that you are answering my question as what I want is that Sidebar becomes a Footer with 100% width for main-area when the Screen width is lower than 750px. Since the sidebar comes first on the HTML markup, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: This isn't even close to answering OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can realize this with **jQuery**.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-area"></div>
<div class="sidebar"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sidebar{
  background-color: #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
}
.main-area{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
  $('.sidebar').css('float', 'right');
  $('.main-area').css('float', 'left');

  $(window).resize(function(){
    if($(this).width() <= 750){
        $('.main-area').removeAttr('style');
        $('.sidebar').removeAttr('style');
    }else{
        $('.sidebar').css('float', 'right');
        $('.main-area').css('float', 'left');
    }
  });
});
```

You can see result here -> [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yC3j7/1/)

Well, this is my way.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer here: http://jsfiddle.net/salman/TPNpy/

```
<div id="main-area-wrap">
  <div id="main-area">Column 1</div>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">Column 2</div>
<div id="clear"></div>

#main-area-wrap{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
#main-area {
    background-color: cyan;
    margin-right: 200px;
}
#sidebar{
    background-color: lime;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
```

Comment: This is essentially what I just edited my post to but without the float: left; on the content hahaha.

Comment: Yeah, you definitely got it. Thanks again :D